# How to get ALL field values from sObject using Rest API

Tags: apex, rest-api

Salesforce documentation [shows how](https://developer.tbsg-crm.net/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_get_field_values.htm) to do this for specific fields, but how do I specify that I want ALL fields/values back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just don't specify the `fields` parameter:

## Return All Fields

```
/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/001...
```

## Return Some Fields

```
/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/001...?fields=Name,Industry,...
```

Comment: Easier than I thought it would be. Thanks! (taking a look at your blog—looks good)